# Creating array from javascript object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a JavaScript object like this

```
server1:[38,1,2,7]
server2:[6,2,1,4
server3:[160,30,21,20]
```

I want to insert the elements of this objects in an array like this

```
data1=[
  [
    {name:"Success", y:38},
    {name:"Failure", y:1},
    {name:"Aborted", y:2},
    {name:"Unstable", y:7}
  ],
  [
    {name:"Success", y:6},
    {name:"Failure", y:2},
    {name:"Aborted", y:1},
    {name:"Unstable", y:4}
  ],
  [
    {name:"Success", y:160},
    {name:"Failure", y:30},
    {name:"Aborted", y:21},
    {name:"Unstable", y:20}
  ]
]
```

The first element of the key of JavaScript object is success, second element is failure, third element is unstable and fourth element is aborted.Is there any way I can do this? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method to get object values and use 
[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
method to generate the array.

```js
const data = {
  server1: [38, 1, 2, 7],
  server2: [6, 2, 1, 4],
  server3: [160, 30, 21, 20]
}


let res = Object.values(data).map(([s, f, a, u]) => [{
    name: "Success",
    y: s
  },
  {
    name: "Failure",
    y: f
  },
  {
    name: "Aborted",
    y: a
  },
  {
    name: "Unstable",
    y: u
  }
])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for the names and map the outer and inner values.

```js
var server1 = [38, 1, 2, 7],
    server2 = [6, 2, 1, 4],
    server3 = [160, 30, 21, 20],
    names = ["Success", "Failure", "Aborted", "Unstable"],
    result = [server1, server2, server3]
        .map(s => names.map((name, i) => ({ name, y: s[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer good ol' loops over functional map() approach, use this:

```js
var test = {
    server1: [38, 1, 2, 7],
    server2: [6, 2, 1, 4],
    server3: [160, 30, 21, 20]
};

function makeArray(input) {
    var array = [];
    for (var server in input) {
        array.push([
            {name: "Success", y : input[server][0]},
            {name: "Failure", y : input[server][1]},
            {name: "Aborted", y : input[server][2]},
            {name: "Unstable", y : input[server][3]},
        ]);
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(makeArray(test));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```